# AccesTokenLifeTime in IdentitySever4 in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: identityserver4

I have ASP.NET Core project and I am using `IdentityServer4` for authorization. For some cases testing, I am setting `AccessTokenLifeTime = 20 seconds`, 
but token expires not after 20 seconds. Once, it expires after 1 minute, once after 5 minutes. How I can set it in right way?

Comment: Which flows and clients do you use?

Comment: I am using iOS client.

Comment: I once faced problems testing my ID4 with that small values. It got better when testing with values 5 min plus. One problem with that small values are different (unsynchronized) clock. On the server it is e.g. 15:04 and on the client it is 15:05. With small testing values there could be a problem.

Comment: If you have token lifetimes of 1 hour a client checking the expires field and thinks it is expired one minute too early does not hurt. If you have only a lifetime of seconds the unsynchronized clocks matter.

Comment: Every time when client gets new access token  from the server, server sets lifetime of the token by his own local time and will be checked by server.By this there could not be a problems for small values.

Comment: Are you familiar with TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew Property? Because if you did not set other value, then default is 5min. So your token is valid for AccessTokenLifeTime + ClockSkew. This is common problem with short live tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more details than in the comments.

One source of your problem could be the combination of small lifetimes and unsynchronized clocks.
Have been there too and went through it too. Took some time to figure it out.

In your scenario you have 3 parts with a clock and manipulating or checking the expires claim token.

The Identity server, the client and the protected resource (PR).

To make the explanation a bit eassier lets assume all work at UTC 0.

Your user gets the access token from ID4 at point midnight, sets issued at to 00:00:00 and expires in 20 seconds makes the token expiring at 00:00:20.

Your client receives the token, wants to use it for a request. Therefor it checks if the token is not already expired.
The client clock is not synchronus to the ID4 clock but ten seconds forward.
So on iOS its not point midnight but already 00:00:10. Since the token expires at 00:00:20 the client says: Lets use that token, it's still valid and sends it to the protected resource.

The clock on the protected resource is 30 seconds a head. So though it should be point midnight when receiving the request it is already 00:00:30.
The token validation checks if the token is still valid, sees that it is valid till 00:00:20 and therefor it is expired. And the protected ressource returns unauthorized.

Some possible steps to reduce that problem.

First of all, do not use lifetimes smaller than 5 minutes. The smaller the lifetime the more weight do clock differences get.

Second step, if possible, try to synchronize clocks on ID4 server and the protected ressource. Works best if they run on the same server.

And finally check your used libraries on the client and the protected resource for settings like clock skew and and when they client requests a new access token. 
If the access token has a liefetime of one hours the client could request a new one 5 min before the token expires.

Comment: I read about this allowed 5min offset somewhere else on SO. In case someone is interested, I found this bug: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1251 which points to a new commit for configuration https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/commit/0eb4364d9dff88da8e87c0bd5eca6219d645e8e5